# Annotation free spring data solution

Tags: java, orm, spring-data-couchbase

It looks like everybody uses annotations to persist data nowadays.

**Why is this a problem?**
Annotations for persistence are specific for the chosen persistence API. If you use MySQL you use @Entity if you use Couchbase, you have to use @Document.

In bigger projects, there is typically an API Layer where one models the objects. This Layer has, or at least should not have, any dependencies to anything database specific.

```
public class User implements IUser {
    private String email;
    private String id;
    private String password;
    private String username;
```

So one can not use @Document here.

The database/persistence layer currently only has this spring-data repository

```
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<IUser, String> {}
```

and the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
```

I expected to find an XML base configuration example, but nothing, annotations all over.
How can I solve this problem?
Is there an XML based approach for the object mapping?
If not, how can this be solved without polluting the API Layer?

Comment: this sounds more like a generic `spring-data` question, as the issue would be the same with other store implementations like `spring-data-jpa` right?

Comment: Yes, this issue is also hits other implementations. If for example Hibernate can be used, for SQL databases, the modelling can be done with xml and without annotations in the API layer...

Answer (score 3):

There is no XML based approach for that. If you need to keep your API layer completely clean, you still need to use a concrete backing store and chose a technology at some point... So it would indicate that you have to add a layer between the API DTOs and what Spring Data persists (entities).

Note that Spring Data applies different conventions to data model depending on the store. For Couchbase, the `@Document` annotation is **not required**, unless you want to deal with *expiry/TTL*.
That said, the `@Id` annotation **is still mandatory** (either from the SDK or from Spring Data Commons, which I would recommend in your case)...

Note also that annotations are declarations. They don't initiate any action without the data store being used for the annotated type.

Spring Data Mongo seems to manage without any annotation if you follow all the conventions (notably the id field being named either `id` or `_id` in the entity POJO), so maybe Spring Data Couchbase could be modified to default to such a convention for the id if no id annotation is found? (good PR potential there ;-)

Comment: Again I agree, annotations are just declarative but they add dependencies that may not be wanted at some point. You soon reach the situation that you have annotations for persistence together with annotations for JSON and more... I don't think that you need an additional layer between API and persistence if you can configure mapping with XML or mixin annotations or good defaults as suggested by you. All this could be done in the persistence layer...